# Laravel collections - list multiple values

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-5

I am looking to take a collection and return flat arrays containing two of the fields from the collection.  What I want:

```
$collection = new Collection([
    [
        "a"=>"a1",
        "b"=>"b1",
        "c"=>"c1"
    ],
    [
        "a"=>"a2",
        "b"=>"b2",
        "c"=>"c2"
    ],
    [
        "a"=>"a3",
        "b"=>"b3",
        "c"=>"c3"
    ]
]);

//desired output:
[
    ["a1","b1"],
    ["a2","b2"],
    ["a3","b3"]
];
```

I would've thought this was a function but it isn't:

```
$collection->lists(["a","b"]);
```

My current solution doesn't seem very efficient given that these may have many thousands of rows:

```
$collection->lists("a")->zip($collection->lists("b"));
```

Is there a function I'm missing?  Thanks.

Edit:  I also have used map like so:

```
$collection->map(function($row)){
    return [$row['a'],$row['b']];
}
```

This seems a bit more custom than I want.  I may end up writing a wrapper for Collection with this function if there isn't a native way..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wanted to specifically use collections you can extend the current Collections API, as it is macroable, doing something like the following:

```php
Collection::macro('pluckMultiple', function ($assoc) {
    return $this->map(function ($item) use ($assoc) {
        $list = [];
        foreach ($assoc as $key) {
            $list[$key] = data_get($item, $key);
        }
        return $list;
    }, new static);
});
```

In the example above I include the key as part of the return, but that can be dropped.

```php
$collection->pluckMultiple(['a', 'b']);
```

would give you what you are looking for.

The above can work nicely if you wanted to pluck items from Eloquent collections, for example:

```php
$books = Book::with('author')->get();
$books->pluckMultiple(['title', 'author.name', 'author.surname']);
```

Comment: This is a great solution thanks. I was actually thrown by this and surprised to see that the pluck method does not accept this by default. It seems like it should to me.

Comment: in which file should this be added written?

Comment: @Ken you can do it in many ways. If you do not have many macros you can put it inside the `register` method of your `AppServiceProvider`. Alternatively you can check the following [forum thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5) for alternatives, to group them in a file and using autoloading.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
$plucked = $collection->pluck('b','a');

$plucked->all();
```

this will give following result

```
Collection {#651 ▼
#items: array:3 [▼
"a1" => "b1"
"a2" => "b2"
"a3" => "b3"
]}
```

and yuse this code to get the given format

```
foreach ($plucked as $key => $item)
{
 $temp[] = [ $key, $item];
}
```

this will givee the following result.

```
array:3 [▼
 0 => array:2 [▼
  0 => "a1"
  1 => "b1"
  ]
 1 => array:2 [▼
  0 => "a2"
  1 => "b2"
  ]
 2 => array:2 [▼
  0 => "a3"
  1 => "b3"
 ]
]
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid going through the array more than once.  I know I can iterate through once using `map()` but it seems like there should be a better way

Comment: I don't think there is any direct function that will give the desired result.

Comment: Thanks.  Will accept your answer if nothing else shows up

Comment: Thank You. and let me know if you find any better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Laravel 5.0 you'll find that `Illuminate\Laravel\Collection` doesn't accept macros, so Leon's elegant solution won't work. If (like me) you can't uprade to a newer Laravel version, you can use this function as a workaround:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

/**
 * List values from collection. Unlike $collection->lists('key'), this function allows using multiple keys.
 *
 * In newer Laravel versions things like that can be done with collection macros, but not in 5.0.
 *
 * @param Collection $collection
 * @param array|string $properties
 * @param string $id
 * @return array
 */
function lists(Collection $collection, $properties, $id = null) {
    $result = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $k = $id ? $item->$id : $i;
        if (is_array($properties)) {
            $result[$k] = [];
            foreach ($properties as $property) {
                $result[$k][$property] = $item->$property;
            }
        }
        else {
            $result[$k] = $item->$properties;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Then you'd use it for example like this:

```
$users = User::all();
$someData = lists($collection, ['name', 'email']);
// Or, if you want to key by id:
$someData = lists($collection, ['name', 'email'], 'id');
```

As for where you'd put this function - I put things like that in app/Support/helpers.php and then update my composer.json like this:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "files": [
        "app/Support/helpers.php"
    ]
},
```

and then run `composer dump`

Answer (score -1):

I modified Leon Vismer answer to use dot notation in an array.

```
        Collection::macro('pluckMultiple', function ($assoc) {
        /* @var $this Collection */
        return $this->map(function ($item) use ($assoc) {
            $list = [];
            foreach ($assoc as $keys) {
                $old_key = $keys;
                $keys    = explode('.', $keys);
                $ref     = &$list;

                while (count($keys) > 1) {
                    $key = array_shift($keys);
                    if (!isset($ref[ $key ]) || !is_array($ref[ $key ])) {
                        $ref[ $key ] = [];
                    }

                    $ref = &$list[ $key ];
                }

                $ref[ array_shift($keys) ] = data_get($item, $old_key);
            }

            return $list;
        }, new static);
    });
```

Comment: No, The output comes out with dots. whereas my code converts the dots into array. example:

   {
      customer.name => 'Raza'
      customer.dob => '1985-01-01'
   }
to
   {
      customer {
         name => 'Raza'
         dob => '1985-01-01'
   }